# delay/slow lve streaming video in Simulink using Raspberry Pi camera

Tags: matlab, simulink, raspberry-pi2

I have a Pi camera module which is attached to pi B board. I am streaming the Live video from Pi camera into Pc Simulink via Edimax Wifi Adaptor Using Router.

By using 10fps and res 320*240, I am facing delay into my Simulink video viewer. Why this delay happens either the speed or range of wifi adaptor or my Laptop processor (i have intel i3 with 4gb RAM 2.4GHZ)

Is there is the way to the reduce the delay?

Comment: I am not completelly sure, but one of the possibilities is because you have a `intel i3 with 4gb RAM 2.4GHZ` and you may need better hardware

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using low image resolution and frame-rate, the only reason you are experiencing such delay can be the limited bandwidth of the WiFi.

If you can, try to wire the Raspberry Pi with an [Ethernet connection](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/5422/Raspberry%20Pi%20Firmware%20Upgrade%20Guide.pdf), you will considerably increase the bandwidth and reduce potential delays of the video transmission.

Comment: ja by connection with ethernet is much faster than WIFI. but my goal of my project wants to do in autonomous (without wire connection).  Might be the reason with Raspberry processor (I have a pi 2) and my laptop processor (i3).. ?

Comment: I don't believe that is a problem of your processor, at the most it can be your graphics card. In my opinion, the trouble is related to the dongle you are using for the WiFI signal that can have limited bandwidth (assuming your WiFi connection is fast). I would go for the Raspberry Pi 3 which has built-in WiFi